# How to resolve NullPointerException in an Activity when calling super class onCreate() method in Android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, oncreate

Hi Friends i have written an Activity like below.

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

protected final int _splashTime = 4000;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {      
        public void run() {
            startActivity(mainIntent);*/
            Main mainObj=new Main();
            final Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            mainObj.onCreate(bundle);
            finish();
        }
    }, _splashTime);
   }
}
```

From the above Activity iam calling Main.java which is as follows.

```
public class Main extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);//line 1.

        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

      }

}
```

In the above Main.java in the line 1 while calling super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) iam getting NullPointerException.I have identified that if i call the Activity by creating an object using new operator it is giving NullPointerException like below

```
Main mainObj=new Main();

final Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

mainObj.onCreate(bundle);
```

But if i call an Activity using

```
startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Main.claass));
```

iam not getting `NullPointerException`.So how can i run an Activity by creating an object using new opertor with out `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can i run an Activity by creating an object using new opertor with out NullPointerException.

You should never attempt to create an instance of an `Activity` using `new`. This is not how Android works. The `Activity` class is a special case in Android (along with several other special Android components) and you need to create and manage them correctly.

To create a new `Activity` you must always create a new `Intent` and use `startActivity(...)` or one of the other `startActivityXXX(...)` methods.

See [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)

Comment: Thank you for the response MisterSquonk.

Comment: @user1195614: You're welcome. Most of the classes used in Android can be treated the same way as any Java class but the core application components (such as `Activity`) need to be treated differently. Make sure to bookmark that link - it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Where is mainIntent defined?
Try this in the thread:

```
public void run() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: MisterSquonk explained it well. Activities are not the same as classes, read up on the Fundamentals link he posted

Comment: Thank you for the response Stu.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the startActivity() method that you already seem to be able to get working.  You do not want to directly call the onCreate() method of your sub-activity.  There is a lot going on behind the scenes that Android is managing for you when you call startActivity.

Here is a link to the developer guide: [Starting An Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#StartingAnActivity)